# Tuple in lambda function meaning

Tags: python

```py
r = Counter(nums)
        
return sorted(nums, key=lambda x: (r[x], -x))
```

I wonder how the `-x` works in this sorted array.

How does this function get translated into which logics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this call to `sorted`:

```
r = Counter(nums)
sorted(nums, key=lambda x: (r[x], -x))
```

The `lambda` argument is just a function that gets called on elements of `nums`, returning the sort key to be used for that element.  The keys are then compared to determine which element should come before the other.

In this case, for an element `x` in `nums`, it's constructing a key `(r[x], -x)`.  So the primary sort key is the value of `r` indexed by `x`.  If those values are equal, then it breaks the tie by comparing `-x`, i.e. the negated values of `x`.  The negation simply causes the comparison to be reversed, so larger values of `x` come before smaller values of `x` rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

By defining `key` argument to `.sorted()` function, you change the way python normally sorts the elements of that iterator. By default you can think of it as : `key = lambda x: x` which means items themselves (no changes).

Here is an example:

```
lst = ['aa', 'bb', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'a', 'b']
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

output : `['aa', 'aaa', 'a', 'bb', 'bbb', 'b']`

As you can see python sorts alphabetically by the "first" character of every item.

When you define a "tuple" let's say `(x, len(x))`, every single items in the list will convert to a **tuple**, so you're actually comparing a tuple with other tuples !

```
print((10, 40) < (10, 30))   # False
```

How do tuples compared with each other ? at first, `x[0]` with `y[0]` if the were equal then `x[1]` with `y[1]` and so on... So basically we defined **priority** with tuples.

```
lst = ['aa', 'bb', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'a', 'b']
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x[0], len(x))))
```

output : `['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'bb', 'bbb']`

It makes sense now, for first item in the list which is `'aa'` the created tuple is `('a' , 2)`, second one is `('b', 2)` etc. So these tuples are compared just like said before.

You don't have to use tuple, lists can be used as well. The comparison algorithm is the same as tuple:

```
lst = ['aa', 'bb', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'a', 'b']
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: [x[0], len(x)]))
```

output : `['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'bb', 'bbb']`

You now know what `-` minus does to your second item of the created tuple.